# AWS Organizations does not allow Backup policy covering af-south-1

Tags: amazon-web-services, backup

We use AWS Backup via a policy set at the AWS Organizations level (in the management account).

I now want to expand the policy to cover the af-south-1 (Cape Town) region, but that region is not offered from the 'Backup plan regions' dropdown.  If I instead edit the JSON, adding af-south-1 causes an error: 'The provided policy document does not meet the requirements of the specified policy type.'

I am aware that the af-south-1 region is opt-in.  I have already opted it in at the management account and all member accounts where it is used.

AWS Backup itself is available in af-south-1.

Anyone seen this themselves, or know the reason for it ?

<edit> the accepted answer covers the reason - thanks, I hadn't spotted that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross-account management is not listed as supported for Africa (Cape Town) region:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-backup/latest/devguide/whatisbackup.html#features-by-region

Answer (score 0):

Further / similar info was also posted in answer to my question over on AWS re:Post [1].
[1] https://repost.aws/questions/QU0bJ2X_7_TuuahGnkYt9NaQ/aws-organizations-does-not-allow-aws-backup-policy-covering-af-south-1